# How to change breadcrumb title?

Tags: google-tag-manager, technical-seo, breadcrumbs

I'm using Google Tag Manager to implement my breadcrumb schema. But instead of the name I'm assigning, breadcrumbs show page title which looks really bad. My script is in JSON-LD and doesn't have any errors.
I've tried changing to HTML script but it didn't work. The title stays the same as page title. Can someone tell me what could I possibly be doing wrong here? Any possible solutions?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "Home",
            "item": "url of home"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "name": "Berkshire",
            "item": "url of berkshire"
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can we see the code in use @Yuri?

Comment: @peter
sure, uploaded the code